# How to execute scripts instead of commands while launching and EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Few bash script files (I have in my computer) needs to execute when the instances are **launched**. Since *user data* field cannot contain files, is there any work around (like using SDK)?

Comment: what exactly is your question? the workaround for what? You can always put the scripts in S3, then copy them to the instance and execute. But you really need to show the code that you wrote! Please improve your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the scripts need to run on the instance you're creating; you can put your scripts in some publicly accessible repository/file system and get it downloaded and executed.
An example would be assuming you are running script1.sh, script2.py, script3.sh; you can store them in an FTP server; while launching you can use tools like curl or wget to get it downloaded in your instance and then run.

## example user data while launching an ec2 instance

```
curl -O xyz.com/scripts.tar
mkdir scripts
tar -xf scripts.tar -C scripts/
cd scripts/
bash script1.sh
```

Comment: I don't this is the correct answer but I thought about posting it while waiting for the right answer.

Comment: Since you are using AWS, it would be better to store the scripts in an Amazon S3 bucket and then use the AWS CLI to download them.